# Elasticsearch random scoring with filters

Tags: elasticsearch

I've got a situation, using ES 6.5, where I can either perform a `bool` or a `random_score`, but not both at the same time. Here is one of those potential queries:

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 50,
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "random_score": {
        "seed": 10,
        "field": "_seq_no"
      }
    },
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "primary_category": [
              "foobar"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "primary_type": [
              "barbaz"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

If I were to remove either the `function_score` block or the `bool` block, the query works, but in combination, it does not:

`[function_score] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]`

Am I missing something about the example at: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-random

All I want to do is "randomly sort" my results in a predictable way which will work across pagination, etc. Really I am just trying to display the filtered results with high variance, as any sort of standard sorting will create patterns in the result which I am trying to avoid.

Any help would be appreciated, and I'll keep tinkering with it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The `function_score` should be part of the `bool` block.